# ListPreference updates its value only when entry is chosen for the second time

Tags: android, locale, android-preferences

When the language in `ListPreference` is changed, `setLanguage()` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/11714703) in `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` method in my `SettingsFragment` class is called.

```
String defaultCode = getActivity().getString(R.string.string_english_code);
String langCode = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_LANGUAGE, defaultCode);
setLanguage(getActivity(), langCode);
((SettingsActivity) getActivity()).restartFragment();
```

Changing a language works fine, but when `setSummary()` is called on the `ListPreference` object in `onCreate()` it changes only when the necessary language is chosen for the second time.

```
ListPreference langPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference(PREF_LANGUAGE);
langPreference.setSummary(langPreference.getEntry());
```

P.S. If `setLanguage()` is not called, summary updates as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
langPreference.setSummary(langPreference.getEntry());
```

Try

```
langPreference.setSummary(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("key", "default value");
```

I use this code to update my Preference summaries, it works everytime.